# MyBatis: compare String value using dynamic query

Tags: java, database, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis to map some queries where I need to compare a `String` argument (`myString`).

My Mapper **interface** is:

`public Map<Integer, String> findSomething(@Param("myString") String myString);`

My **XML** is as follow:

```
<select id="findSomething" parameterType="String" resultType="Map">
    SELECT column1 as key,
           column2 as value
    FROM my_table
    <where>
         <choose>
            <when test="myString == 'xxx'">
                column3 = 1
            </when>
            <when test="myString == 'yyy'">
                myColumn  = 2
            </when>
            <when test="myString == 'zzz'">
                myColumn  = 3
            </when>
        </choose>
    </where>
    ORDER BY value;
</select>
```

When I execute this statement the following error is throwed:

```
ERROR [stderr] Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
ERROR [stderr] ### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'myString' in 'class java.lang.String'
```

A `String` comparison made this way, smells bad. Unfortunately it was the way database was modeled.

MyBatis version: `3.2.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely I had to go through a complicated approach.

Changed mapper method signature:

```
public Map<Integer, String> findSomething(@Param("myPojo") MyPojo myPojo);
```

The **XML** must be:

```
<select id="findSomething" resultType="Map">
SELECT column1 as key,
       column2 as value
FROM my_table
<where>
     <choose>
        <when test="myPojo == 'xxx'">
            column3 = 1
        </when>
        <when test="myPojo == 'yyy'">
            myColumn  = 2
        </when>
        <when test="myPojo == 'zzz'">
            myColumn  = 3
        </when>
    </choose>
</where>
ORDER BY value;
```

Just don't forget, being a POJO, the parameter class must have it's respective getters and setters.

Comment: too bad you went to "complicated approach", your original code was not far from the truth: all you had to do is dropping `parameterType="String"` from the statement, then the parameter type becomes implicitly a map because you named the parameter with `@Param("myString")`.

Answer (score 7):

Tested with MyBatis 3.2.8

```
<select id="findSomething" parameterType="String" resultType="Map">
    SELECT column1 as key,
           column2 as value
    FROM my_table
    <where>
         <choose>
            <when test='"xxx".equals(myString)'>
                column3 = 1
            </when>
            <when test='"yyy".equals(myString)'>
                myColumn  = 2
            </when>
            <when test='"zzz".equals(myString)'>
                myColumn  = 3
            </when>
        </choose>
    </where>
    ORDER BY value;
</select>
```

Note the single quotes around test and the double quotes around de constant values. The trick is to use equals as you can see.

Comment: MyBatis allows the usage of '==' syntax for string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Mybatis 3.2.2 and above, Revise your xml to the following and see if it helps:

```
<select id="findSomething" parameterType="String" resultType="Map">
SELECT column1 as key,
       column2 as value
FROM my_table
<where>
     <choose>
        <when test="value == 'xxx'">
            column3 = 1;
        </when>
        <when test="value == 'yyy'">
            myColumn  = 2;
        </when>
        <when test="value == 'zzz'">
            myColumn  = 3;
        </when>
    </choose>
</where>
ORDER BY value;
```

Comment: Actually I need to compare the argument received by method, not the column specified by query. Check the method signature in the question.

Comment: Might not be the answer to the question but it was the only working way of comparing strings for me.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution should be mentioned:

```
<where>
     <choose>
        <when test='value == "xxx"'>
            column3 = 1;
        </when>
        <when test='value == "yyy"'>
            myColumn  = 2;
        </when>
        <when test='value == "zzz"'>
            myColumn  = 3;
        </when>
    </choose>
</where>
```