# How to query the value of a static parameter of MyBatis <sql> fragment?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

Is it possible in MyBatis to combine **statically parametrized** `<sql>` [reusable fragments](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#sql) with `<if>` [dynamic SQL](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#if)?

How to query the value of a **static** (= *not* coming from Java method, but entered directly in the mapper XML) parameter of MyBatis `<sql>` fragment?

The question is *not* how to compare `String` values in MyBatis, but how to *query the value of a **static** parameter*.

I am trying to call the reusable element `select-part` with a static parameter `source`.

I have tried various ways of writing the `<if test="...">` condition but all fail:

- `<if test="source == 'active'">`
- `<if test="${source} == 'active'">`
- `<if test="#{source} == 'active'">`

The simplified mapper XML is something like this:

```xml
<sql id="select-part">
    SELECT d.field1, d.field2, ..., d.fieldN
    <if test="${source} == 'active'">
        , null AS archivedDate
        FROM active_table d
    </if>
    <if test="${source} == 'archive'">
        , d.achived AS archivedDate
        FROM archive_table d
    </if>
    LEFT JOIN ...
    ORDER BY ...
</sql>

<select id="fetchData" resultMap="Data">
    <include refid="select-part">
        <property name="source" value="active"/>
    </include>
    UNION ALL
    <include refid="select-part">
        <property name="source" value="archive"/>
    </include>
</select>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450304/mybatis-compare-string-value-using-dynamic-query try to use equals

Comment: @StanislavL The question is NOT how to compare Strings, but how to access the static parameter. The problem is how to query the value of source variable. It does not behave the same as if the value comes from the Java method. I edited the question and change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, current implementation has a "bug" that it does not replace placeholders in XML attributes in the SQL fragments. Only placeholders in text nodes are replaced. I consider this as a bug in the implementation which should be fixed. I have implemented that in my fork: https://github.com/kmoco2am/mybatis-3 and I will try to push into the original repository.

Comment: Pull request is open here for this:
https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1070